# Video processing with ATI cards

Tags: video, graphics-card

A friend of mine is about to purchase either an 4870 or an 4890 ATI card. He is deeply envious of the GPU-video processing that is now available on NVIDIA through CUDA with a number of video processing softwares.

Is there something similar available for ATI? What video processing softwares support it? And does the 4890 present any significant advantage over the 4870 for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [ATI Video Converter](http://ati.amd.com/technology/Avivo/technology.html), which should be built into the latest Catalyst driver downloads.

It is accessible through the Catalyst Control Center, and according to the blurb should be able to transcode video up to 17x faster than CPU alone, e.g. one hour of video could be converted to portable player format in 12 minutes.

Edit: according to a recent Anandtech [review](http://www.anandtech.com/video/showdoc.aspx?i=3578), it's not very good.  And it looks like you need to download it separately to the drivers.

Answer (score 2):

The ATI video converter is, unfortunately, unusable for any serious encoding work. What's also dissappointing is that software makers such as Adobe typically support CUDA but not ATI, possibly because the CUDA toolkit is better and more popular.

Comment: That's *still* the case? Wow, how disappointing!

Answer (score 1):

ATI Stream (I believe is the name) is the ATI version of this type of software. It is not supported by ATI at all currently. Someone may be able to update this thread when it is supported.

Comment: ATI Stream is the ATI equivalent of NVIDIA's CUDA.

Comment: Yes, but from what I read Stream has about 1% of the official support that CUDA does, which is exactly what the question asked.